# sorting results after get;set parameter

Tags: c#

```
public struct Säljare
{
    public String Namn;
    public String Personnummer;
    public String Distrikt;
    public int AntalArtiklar;

    public string NAMN
    {
        get { return Namn; }
        set { Namn = value; }
    }
    public string PERSONNUMMER
    {
        get { return this.Personnummer; }
        set { this.Personnummer = value; }
    }
    public string DISTRIKT
    {
        get { return Distrikt; }
        set { Distrikt = value; }
    }
    public int ANTALARTIKLAR
    {
        get { return AntalArtiklar; }
        set { AntalArtiklar = value; }
    }
    public int NIVA1
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.AntalArtiklar > 199) return 4;
            if (this.AntalArtiklar > 99) return 3;
            if (this.AntalArtiklar > 49) return 2;
            if (this.AntalArtiklar > 1) return 1;
            else return 0;

        }
    }

    public Säljare(string Namn1, string Personnummer1, string Distrikt1, int AntalArtiklar1)
    {
        this.Namn = Namn1;
        this.Personnummer = Personnummer1;
        this.Distrikt = Distrikt1;
        this.AntalArtiklar = AntalArtiklar1;

    }

    public void SkrivUtInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", this.Namn, this.Personnummer, this.Distrikt, this.AntalArtiklar);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        {
            List<Säljare> salesmen = new List<Säljare>();

            var nivaMax = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare6 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare1 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare2 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare3 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare4 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Var Vänlig och skriv in info för säljaren (1,Namn (enter),2, persnr (enter),3, Distrikt(enter),4, AntalArtiklar (enter), 5,Niva 1-4(enter)");
            var saljare5 = new Säljare(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(), Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));

            var saljare = new Säljare();
            var Niva = saljare.NIVA1;

            nivaMax = Math.Max(nivaMax, Niva);

            salesmen.Add(saljare1);
            salesmen.Add(saljare2);
            salesmen.Add(saljare3);
            salesmen.Add(saljare4);
            salesmen.Add(saljare5);
            salesmen.Add(saljare6);

            for (int level = 0; level < 4; level++)
            {
                var salesmenAtLevel = 1;
                foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)
                {
                    if (saljare1.NIVA1 == level)
                    {
                        salesmenAtLevel++;
                    }
                }
                if (salesmenAtLevel > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare1.NAMN, saljare1.PERSONNUMMER, saljare1.DISTRIKT, saljare1.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel, saljare1.NIVA1);

                    Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");

                }

                for (int level1 = 1; level1 < 4; level1++)
                {
                    var salesmenAtLevel1 = 1;
                    foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)

                        if (saljare2.NIVA1 == level1)
                        {
                            salesmenAtLevel1++;
                        }

                    if (salesmenAtLevel1 > 0)

                        Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare2.NAMN, saljare2.PERSONNUMMER, saljare2.DISTRIKT, saljare2.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                        Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel1, saljare2.NIVA1);

                        Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
                    }

                    for (int level2 = 0; level2 < 4; level2++)
                    {
                        var salesmenAtLevel2 = 1;
                        foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)

                            if (saljare3.NIVA1 == level2)
                            {
                                salesmenAtLevel2++;
                            }
                        if (salesmenAtLevel2 > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare3.NAMN, saljare3.PERSONNUMMER, saljare3.DISTRIKT, saljare3.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                            Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel2, saljare3.NIVA1);

                            Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
                        }

                        for (int level3 = 0; level3 < 4; level3++)
                        {
                            var salesmenAtLevel3 = 1;
                            foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)
                            {
                                if (saljare4.NIVA1 == level3)
                                {
                                    salesmenAtLevel3++;
                                }
                            }
                            if (salesmenAtLevel3 > 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare4.NAMN, saljare4.PERSONNUMMER, saljare4.DISTRIKT, saljare4.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                                Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel3, saljare4.NIVA1);

                                Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
                            }
                            for (int level4 = 0; level4 < 4; level4++)
                            {
                                var salesmenAtLevel4 = 1;
                                foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)
                                {
                                    if (saljare5.NIVA1 == level4)
                                    {
                                        salesmenAtLevel4++;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (salesmenAtLevel4 > 0)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare5.NAMN, saljare5.PERSONNUMMER, saljare5.DISTRIKT, saljare5.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                                    Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel4, saljare5.NIVA1);


                                    Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
                                }

                                for (int level5 = 0; level5 < 4; level5++)
                                {

                                    var salesmenAtLevel5 = 1;
                                    foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)
                                    {
                                        if (saljare6.NIVA1 == level5)
                                        {

                                            salesmenAtLevel5++;

                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (salesmenAtLevel5 > 0)
                                    {

                                        Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare6.NAMN, saljare6.PERSONNUMMER, saljare6.DISTRIKT, saljare6.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                                        Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel5, saljare6.NIVA1);


                                             Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
```

My Problem is that i want to sort my Saljare1-6 after which NIVA1 they have reached. At the moment I get the correct information but they come in the order of when its typed in.

What i want it to be like is that if 2 sellers have reached over 200 sales(level 4) then it will be shown as:
seller(saljare) info 1
seller info 2
2 sellers have reached level 4.

And the same for all other levels.

EDIT: There is 6 of these, the end value is correct but it is not in the correct order. I want to have the sellers sorted after which NIVA1 they reach. How can i sort them into giving me ALL sellers and their info reaching level 1 after each other followed by "2 sellers have reached level 1". After this all sellers reaching level 2 gets presented followed by"1 sellers reached level 2".

When i try using a Sorted List i get a ArgumentException because of that more than one seller reached a certain level.

```
for (int level = 0; level < 4; level++)
            {

                var salesmenAtLevel = 1;
                foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)
                {
                    if (saljare1.NIVA1 == level)
                    {

                        salesmenAtLevel++;

                    }
                }
                if (salesmenAtLevel > 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}", saljare1.NAMN, saljare1.PERSONNUMMER, saljare1.DISTRIKT, saljare1.ANTALARTIKLAR);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}", salesmenAtLevel, saljare1.NIVA1);


                    Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");

                }
```

EDIT2: I get the ArgumentException below, depending on when it reaches more then one seller per NIVA1.

```
                               SortedList s = new SortedList();
                                        s.Add(saljare1.NIVA1, saljare1);
                                        s.Add(saljare2.NIVA1, saljare2);
                                        s.Add(saljare3.NIVA1, saljare3);
                                        s.Add(saljare4.NIVA1, saljare4);
                                        s.Add(saljare5.NIVA1, saljare5);
                                        s.Add(saljare6.NIVA1, saljare6);

                                        for (int j = 0; j < s.Count; j++)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", s.GetKey(j), s.GetKey(j));
                                        }

                                    }
                                    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Please format the code more readable. Preferrably, create a minimal example to present your question.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully its easier to understand.

Comment: What is `saljare1` in your `foreach (Säljare saljaren in salesmen)` loop? Since you do `var salesmenAtLevel = 1;` initially, the `if (salesmenAtLevel > 0)` condition is always going to be satisfied. Where exactly do you get the argument exception?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the salesman have to be ordered by `NIVA1` and then grouped, the members of each group have to be counted an the group has to be printed. This can be done conceputally easier and with less code repetition as follows.

```
foreach (var iGroup in salesmen.GroupBy( iSalesman => iSalesman.NIVA1 )
                                .OrderBy(aGroup => aGroup.Key))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} salesmen have reached nivå {1}",
                       iGroup.Count,
                       iGroup.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------SUMMARY--------------");
    foreach(var iSalesman in iGroup)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Namn = {0} && Personnummer = {1} && Distrikt = {2} && AntalArtiklar = {3}",
            iSalesman.NAMN,
            iSalesman.PERSONNUMMER,
            iSalesman.DISTRIKT,
            iSalesman.ANTALARTIKLAR);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```